# Where can I find a multioscillator synth?

Tags: synthesizer, sound-design

I need synth where I could use some oscillators (unlimited amount the best) and make them influence each other. For example I could choose for first to be multiplied by second to make the result and so on. Or I could use mathematical expressions to design waves. Any ideas?

I am using Linux as my operating system.

ADD:

I'd like also not only add them together but for example make function which could represent changing of volume or frequency in time. (When track is starting up they use increasing frequency sound like in thunder-prodigy). Something more expended.

Comment: Can you say more about what you'd like to do with the oscillators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could start out with a powerful "[Analog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_synthesis)" style or [FM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation_synthesis) style synth like Native Instruments' Massive or [FM8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM8).

If you are really focused on [additive synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_synthesis) or you'd just like something more flexible, consider the following modular environments:

Linux Friendly:

- [CSound](http://www.csounds.com/) - text mode synthesis and composition language. Extremely powerful, moderately steep learning curve
- [SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/) - text mode synthesis language. Extremely powerful, steep learning curve. More modern than CSound
- [PureData](http://puredata.info/) - graphical modular environment. Very powerful, moderate learning curve

Windows / OSX:

- [Max/MSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_%28software%29) - essentially a commercial and more pretty version of PureData (or vice-versa)
- Native Instruments' [Reaktor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaktor) - commercial modular environment. Great if you want access to their huge library of community synths

Comment: What do you think of the Novation UltraNova ?

Comment: The UltraNova is probably the best value in polysynths out there. I had a SuperNova II back when they were new, and loved everything about it. The UltraNova is essentially the same thing in a smaller package without multitimbrality. If I didn't already have a Virus TI2, I'd probably get one.

Comment: waou, impressive. Didn't know it was such a killer synth.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux I recommend supercollider or pure data. There are also other modular synths on Linux, which are more turn key than PD or supercollider, which are more like programming languages. Check out this project http://alsamodular.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

Besides whats' posted above ZynAddSubFX is probably the simplest.
Does additive, FM, AM, Subtractive as well as ifft based synthesis